# ArrayList in one class is updated using GUI but is not changing in the JComboBox in another

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jcombobox

I have a multi-frame GUI program and one of the problems is that when I add an Object to the ArrayList in Class1, it does not reflect in the JComboBox of Class2.

Some background:

I have a NewDepartmentFrame that adds Departments to a SystemData class. The SystemData class contains a accessor called getAllDepartments()

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SystemData {
    private static ArrayList<Department> departments = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Department> getAllDepartments() {
        return (ArrayList<Department>) departments.clone();
    }
    //there is more to this class, but I don't think it is relevant for the
    //question at the moment
}
//here is part of another class called NewDepartmentFrame that adds the 
//department

public class NewDepartmentFrame extends JFrame{

public Department saveDepartment (){
   Department temp = new Department(dName, dLocation);
   SystemData.addDepartment(temp);
   return temp;
}

public class Listeners implements ActionListener{
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource() == bSave){
           dName = tAdd.getText();
           tAdd.setText("");
           main.add(bSave);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "You have entered a new department");
           saveDepartment();
}

//I know that my code is quite messy but I'm still new to Java
public class EmployeeFrame extends JFrame {
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JLabel lfName = new JLabel("First Name ");
    private JLabel llName = new JLabel("Last Name ");
    private JLabel lAddress = new JLabel("Address ");
    private JLabel lEmployee = new JLabel("Enter Employee ID");
    private JLabel lPLevel = new JLabel("Pay Level ");
    private JLabel lDepartment = new JLabel("Department");

    private JTextField fName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField lName = new JTextField();
    private JTextField address = new JTextField();
    private JTextField employee = new JTextField();

    private JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("Male");
    private JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("Female");
    private ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    private JComboBox pLevel = new JComboBox();
    private JComboBox department = new JComboBox();

    private JButton bAlter = new JButton("Alter");
    private JButton bDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    private JButton bAdd = new JButton("Add");
    private JButton bClear = new JButton("Clear");
    private JButton bSave = new JButton("Save");
    private JButton bClose = new JButton("Close");

    private String fNameInput;
    private String lNameInput;
    private int payLevel;
    private boolean alter = false;
    private String input;
    private int empID = Employee.getId();

    private Employee e = new Employee();
    private Employee temp;
    private Department d = new Department();
    private JPanel main = new JPanel();
    private TheListeners l = new TheListeners();

    public EmployeeFrame() {
        frame.setTitle("Manage Employees");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.add(main);

        for (double d : e.getPayList()) {
            pLevel.addItem(d);
        }

        department.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(SystemData.getAllDepartments().toArray()));
        //why does it not reflect the new Department added to the ArrayList

        main.add(lfName);
        fName.setColumns(ALLBITS);
        main.add(fName);
        main.add(llName);
        lName.setColumns(ALLBITS);
        main.add(lName);

        main.add(b1);
        main.add(b2);
        bGroup.add(b1);
        bGroup.add(b2);

        main.add(lAddress);
        address.setColumns(ALLBITS);
        main.add(address);

        main.add(lPLevel);
        main.add(pLevel);

        main.add(lDepartment);

        main.add(department);

        main.add(lEmployee);
        employee.setColumns(ALLBITS);
        main.add(employee);

        bSave.setEnabled(false);
        main.add(bAlter);
        main.add(bDelete);
        main.add(bAdd);
        main.add(bClear);
        main.add(bSave);
        main.add(bClose);

        //add listeners
        b1.addItemListener(l);
        b2.addItemListener(l);

        bAlter.addActionListener(l);
        bDelete.addActionListener(l);
        bAdd.addActionListener(l);
        bClear.addActionListener(l);
        bSave.addActionListener(l);
        bClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        //main.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class TheListeners implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
        private SystemData s = new SystemData();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == bAdd) {
                bSave.setEnabled(true);
                String input1 = fName.getText();
                String input2 = lName.getText();
                String input3 = address.getText();
                int input4 = (Integer) pLevel.getSelectedIndex();
                input4++; //add one so that it returns the correct paylevel
                System.out.println("test1");
                boolean gender;
                Department d = (Department) department.getSelectedItem();
                gender = b1.isSelected();

                temp = new Employee(input1, input2, gender, input3, input4, d);
                System.out.println(temp.toString());
            } else if (e.getSource() == bClear) {
                bSave.setEnabled(false);
                fName.setText("");
                lName.setText("");
                address.setText("");
                pLevel.setSelectedItem(null);
                department.setSelectedItem(null);
                employee.setText("");
                System.out.println("test2");

            } else if (e.getSource() == bAlter) {
                String input = employee.getText();
                int empID = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println("test3");

                temp = SystemData.getEmployee(empID);
                if (temp != null) {
                    fName.setText(temp.getFirstName());
                    lName.setText(temp.getLastName());
                    b1.setSelected(temp.isGender());
                    b2.setSelected(temp.isGender());
                    address.setText(temp.getAddress());
                    pLevel.setSelectedIndex(temp.getPayLevel() - 1);
                    department.setSelectedItem(temp.getCurDepartment());

                    alter = true;
                    System.out.println("test4");
                }
            } else if (e.getSource() == bDelete) {
                System.out.println("test5");
                String input = employee.getText();
                int empID = Integer.parseInt(input);
                System.out.println("test6");

                 /*temp = SystemData.getEmployee(empID);

                 if(!(empID < 10000 || empID > 29999)){
                     if(temp != null){
                        fName.setText(temp.getFirstName());
                        lName.setText(temp.getLastName());
                        b1.setSelected(temp.isGender());
                        b2.setSelected(temp.isGender());
                        address.setText(temp.getAddress());
                        pLevel.setSelectedIndex(temp.getPayLevel() - 1);
                        department.setSelectedItem(temp.getCurDepartment());

                        SystemData.deleteEmployee(empID);

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have deleted "+ temp.toString() + "from the database");

                 }
                 else{

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid ID");

                 }
                */

            } else if (e.getSource() == bSave) {
                if (alter) {
                    bSave.setEnabled(true);
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setFirstName(fName.getText());
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setLastName(lName.getText());
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setAddress(address.getText());
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setPayLevel(pLevel.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setCurDepartment((Department) department.getSelectedItem());
                    SystemData.getEmployee(empID).setGender(b1.isSelected());
                    bSave.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    //bSave.setEnabled(false);
                    fName.setText("");
                    lName.setText("");
                    address.setText("");
                    pLevel.setSelectedItem(null);
                    department.setSelectedItem(null);
                    employee.setText("");

                    System.out.println(empID);
                    SystemData.setEmployees(empID, temp);
                    //d.setEmployees(temp);
                    empID++;
                    //SystemData.employees.put(empID, temp);
                    //d.setEmployees(temp);
                    int print = empID - 1;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've added a new employee. \n ID number:" + print);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getItem().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not find where the department is being added (a bit too much/(wrong?) code here), but `getAllDepartments` is cloning the list - adding to the original list (or a clone) will not add to the (other) clone(s)!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yeah, my code is confusing even for me. I'm hoping it gets better with practice. My department is actually added in my 'NewDepartmentFrame' class. Let me add it to my question then you will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to use the `DefaultComboBoxModel` as the data model for the combo box. Swing is based on a pattern called MVC :

- M for Model, hence the `DefaultComboBoxModel`
- V for View, your JComboBox
- C for controller, links the view and the model

Use the [DefaultComboBoxModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#getSelectedItem--) to store the `departments` and the method `addDepartment` will add a new department to this model by calling `addElement`. Everytime you add an element to this model, the combo box will be updated automatically.

You can find an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javax.swing/DefaultComboBoxModel/0100__DefaultComboBoxModel.addElement_E_anObject_.htm)